# How to prove or disprove $P(\overline A) = P(U) - P(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Edit: P(U) and P(A) refer to Power Sets.

I don't know how to prove, or disprove, $P(\overline A) = P(U) - P(A)$.

My initial thoughts is that the statement is true: If I have a set A in universe U, removing set A would leave me with $(U - A)$

$U - A$ implies $A \cap \overline U$

If $y \in U$, then $y \in A$ because A is a set in U (not sure if I can call this a subset ?).

However, $A \cap \overline U$ = $A \cap \emptyset$ = $\emptyset$

So $\mathcal{P(\overline{A})} \not = \emptyset$

However, I cannot think of a contradictory condition.  If $x \in A$, then by definition, $x \in U$ - $x \in A$ = $x \notin A$, which, I think, agrees with the original question (that P($\overline A $)).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you clarify what $P(A)$ stands for? And what exactly do you mean by the statement "$U-A$ implies $A\cap \overline{U}$"?

Comment: Also, your notation is somewhat obscure: A probability cannot equal (or unequal...) the empty set $\emptyset$.

Comment: If by $\mathcal P(A)$ you mean the *power-set* of a set $A$, then $\mathcal P(U)$ does not exists, because the "universe" $U$ is not a set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, in situations like this is a standard convention to assume that $U$ refers to some "universal set", i.e. an actual set in which the other sets in question sit inside of.

Comment: @Tim, there seems to be much confusion in your post. As stated in another comment, what does "$U-A$ implies $A \cap \overline U$" mean? How does one set imply another set? Also "if $y \in U$, then $y \in A$" is false: $A$ is a subset of $U$ but what you're saying would require that $U$ be a subset of $A$. As for your actual question, the common way to try to show that two sets are equal is to show that they are subsets of each other, did you try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(A)$  and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(\bar{A})$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(U)$

so $\emptyset \in\mathcal{P}(\bar{A})$ but  $\emptyset \not \in \mathcal{P}(U)-\mathcal{P}(A)$

Answer (score 0):

$A \cap \bar{A}=\emptyset$ and $A \cup \bar{A}=U$ so by the [third probability axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom) $\Pr(A) + \Pr(\bar{A})=\Pr(U)$.

Comment: This is about power set, not probability.

Comment: OK - I will give another answer